# Two column layout for stage play

Tags: formatting

I know there is a couple of document classes specifically designed for stage play scripts, but as far as I could tell, none offered the feature I'm looking for. I want the names of the characters to be in their own column, with their lines left justified in their own column. Like this:

```
Daniel  Hi there, what are you up to?
Anna    I was just gonna go to the store to
        grab some groceries, do you want some-
        thing?
Daniel  A pack of gum would be nice, thanks!
```

My feeling is, that using a table for this kind of purpose is wrong. It would also most certainly lead to page breaking issues. What would be the ideal way of achieving this? I don't really want to abuse margin notes, as I'm planning on using them as well. Or does a certain class designed for stage plays include this feature?

Comment: see, if `description` list gives what you after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending Zarko's nice idea, I would define a custom description environment `play` using the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/emumitem) package and define some commands for the actors names `\Anna`, `\Daniel`, `\Susan` etc so that you can write the play in a more intuitive way as

```
\begin{play}
\Daniel  Hi there, what are you up to?
\Anna    I was just gonna go to the store to grab some
groceries, do you want something?
\Daniel  A pack of gum would be nice, thanks!
\end{play}
```

It would also be good to have a "direction command" that allows you to "interrupt" the dialogue and add stage directions. To set the width of the "actor column" and to define the macros for the actor's names I have added another command:

```
\DeclareActors{Daniel, Anna, Susan}
```

Putting this together your play begins to take shape as:

[image]

You can further customise the `play` environment by reading the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) manual. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% define some macros for the play
\newlist{play}{description}{1}
\newlength\widthofactor
\newlength\widthofactors% will become width of widest actor name
\setlength\widthofactors{10mm}
\newcommand\DeclareActors[1]{% define actor commands
   \renewcommand*\do[1]{
     \csdef{##1}{\item[##1]}
     \setlength\widthofactor{\widthof{##1\quad}}
     \ifdim\widthofactors<\widthofactor
       \setlength\widthofactors\widthofactor
     \fi
   }
   \docsvlist{#1}
   \setlist[play]{labelwidth=\widthofactors, leftmargin=!}
}
\newcommand\Direction[1]{\end{play}\textit{#1}\begin{play}}

%%%%

\DeclareActors{Daniel, Anna, Susan}

\begin{document}

\begin{play}
\Daniel  Hi there, what are you up to?
\Anna    I was just gonna go to the store to grab some
groceries, do you want something?
\Daniel  A pack of gum would be nice, thanks!
\Direction{Anna exits stage left, going to the shops}
\Susan   What's on your mind?
\end{play}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you actually made base for new package :-). bravo! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with the dramatist package. see see https://www.ctan.org/topic/drama-script

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book} % use oneside to allow geometry to keep text always left
\usepackage{dramatist} % INMHO best of related packages i.e. Theatre Stage Play Frankinstein etc. 
\usepackage{calc} %required for length adjustments
\usepackage[left=20mm,right=45mm]{geometry} % minimise left & allow for right hand notes
\setlength{\speakswidth}{\widthof{\speaksfont Daniel}} % we need to allow for the longest name unless we abreviate him to Dan throughout see character definitions later
\addtolength{\speakswidth}{\Dlabelsep} % required for first column spacing
\setlength{\speaksindent}{0mm} % maintains second line indent
% The following shortcuts must not conflict with any likely or known abbreviated command e.g. beware ans or das may be defined elsewhere
\def\ans{\annspeaks} %\lowercase short name speaks to ease repetitive typing 
\def\das{\danspeaks} % one entry per character see cast-list in main body

\title{All'o'World's a stage\\ \it or ``As I like it''\normalfont}
\author{Philipp Stephan}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\Character[\Large Anna(stagia) - An na'ctress\normalsize]{Anna}{ann}  % define characters and alias, the last variant is for ease of typing \annspeaks
\Character[\Large Daniel - A-lad-in This word play\normalsize]{Daniel}{dan} % the short form \dan can be expanded in text see last dialogue

\DramPer[\\~\newline A Cast of a Thousand \\ Less 998 miserables \\ = Our two thespians \par] %\DramPer % recommended two empty lines below

\clearpage
\scene[- A Sitting Room] % recommended one empty line below

\StageDir{\centering Raise the house - it's curtains for us.}

\dan \direct{Enters and moving centre stage, turns towards \ann}.
\begin{drama}
\das \direct{Brightly}.  Hi there, what are you up to?
\ans I was just gonna go to the store to grab some groceries, do you want something?
\das A pack of gum would be nice, thanks!
\ans \direct{Pensively}. But \dan a pack of Vivamus varius tellus et mi pretium elementum iaculis tellus semper. Donec semper iaculis ante, convallis convallis arcu laoreet vitae. Aliquam id leo ac eros ultrices rhoncus porta sed ipsum. 
\end{drama}

\centering - The End -
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this package, but I need two sided layout. `dramatist` messed with the margins and it collided with `lineno` and margin notes. I couln't get header marks for act and scene working with KOMA-script, so I resided to using the description list version.